# Prioritizing one table during the join BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two table in the BigQuery with the same schemas. First contains historical records of products, the second - the most recent products. My goal is to make a join of two tables so that whenever product id isn't in the second table we use row from historical data, but when we have intersection of product ids that are not in the historical, then we use row from the second table (with the most recent data).

My first solution was to use UNION ALL with windowing function to discard duplicates on the intersection, but I was wondering if there is another approach with some kind of a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` for this scenario. By using `FULL OUTER JOIN` it will return all fields and columns including the null values. I created 2 tables matching your scenario:

`tblA` as historical table:

[image]

`tblB` as recent table:

[image]

Notice that there are `product_id` = **0050** on both tables but with different product, `tblA` has `product`=**'Jelly'** and `tblB` has `product`=**'Ace'**. As your requirement, you need to prioritize the results that will come from the `tblB` which is `product`=**'Ace'**, as the table that is containing the recent data. And when there is no existing data/null in `tblB` you can reference with `tblA`. This query satisfies the requirement:

```
SELECT product_id, COALESCE(b.product, a.product) AS product 
FROM `tblA` AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN `tblB` AS b  USING (product_id)
ORDER BY product_id;
```

Result:

[image]

`COALESCE` returns the value of the first non-null expression, hence by putting `b.product` as first in the parameter, it will give back result from the first result if satisfied. If not, it will check the second in parameter which is `a.product`.